# Fedora battery life and tick_sched_timer

Tags: fedora, power-management, powertop

I recently installed Fedora 30 for work on my Gigabyte Aero 15X v8. I blacklisted nouveau drivers as I don't need the discrete GPU while working and installed TLD. But even after that, the battery life is around 4-4:30 h versus more than 6 on Windows.

I installed powertop to see what's going on and I saw that this tick_sched_timer was drawing more than half of the laptop's power. Apparently quite a few other people experience it from what I searched, but I coudn't find either an explanation or a solution.

[image: Powertop output]

Is it normal ? Or is there something that can be done ?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Kinda... Apparently the power consumption displayed by powertop is a rough estimate and is in this case completely wrong. The global discharge rate is right, but how it is spread between the processes is not.
In my case I believe the issue is that the dGPU is still drawing some power, but I didn't have time to look too much into it